# How to make rails code reloaded each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'd like to play with rails code to understand it deeper and how everything works internally. And it could be very nice to change rails code and see the changes after reloading page (by default I need to restart server), what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't need to restart your server just refresh your page, except for adding migrations

also you can play with your rails app interactively using the rails console similar to irb

just type **rails console** or **rails c** into your app directory

Comment: For example, I'd like to see how the "render" method works, I know from rubymine that it's located here "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb". Next I'd like to make some changes and byebug command. But I need to restart server to see the changes. Why shouldn't I need to do that?

Comment: like for the example you gave me I'd go to https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb

Comment: Thx, but I've seen the code and my question is how could I make that code reloaded without server restarting.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do that. I normally just refresh my browser for code changes in mvc but your editing the rails framework, I haven't dug that deep yet.